# Issue creating a single .d.ts when using external modules

Tags: npm, typescript

I'm developing an NPM package using typescript. Within this package the TS files are setup as external modules. The compiler won't generate a single .d.ts for external modules. I'm trying to concat all tsc generated type definitions into a single .d.ts for the entire package.

I'm having issues laying out the single .d.ts file (following a similar approach to that used in `grunt-dts-bundle`). The condensed example below captures my issue.

Given this external module declaration and test file:

`test.d.ts` :

```
declare module "ExternalWrapper" {
    export import Foo = require("FooModule");
}

declare module "FooModule" {
    class Foo {
        name: string;
    }
     export = Foo;
}
```

`test.ts`:

```
import externalWrapper = require( 'ExternalWrapper' );
var t = new externalWrapper.Foo();
```

Running `tsc test.ts test.d.ts -m commonjs` produces this error: `TS2083: Invalid 'new' expression.`

If you change 'test.ts' to look like this, importing 'FooModule' directly:

```
import Foo = require( "FooModule" );
var t = new Foo();
```

It compiles fine.

The compiler understands the type `externalWrapper.Foo` however it doesn't seem to represent it as the same type `FooModule.Foo`. There is something I'm not getting about how the compilers handles modules that are exported via 'export import'.

Failing the above I'll probably look to manually creating the .d.ts :(

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing a `reference` tag:

```
/// <reference path="test.d.ts"/>
```

It works :

[image]

Comment: cheers, that was it. I've seen your issue on external module .d.ts generations over on the typescript issues list, hopefully this goes away if that gets implemented :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix this by modifying your .d.ts file to resemble the following:

```
declare module "ExternalWrapper" {
    import FooModule = require("FooModule");
    export var Foo: typeof FooModule;
}

declare module "FooModule" {
    class Foo {
        name: string;
    }
    export = Foo;
}
```

With the `export import` syntax the compiler was assuming you were exporting an instance of Foo, not Foo itself... a little quirky.